# how to configure open ldap to work on localhost

Tags: configuration, ldap, openldap

From the documentation:

> Use your favorite editor to edit the
>   provided slapd.conf(5) example
>   (usually installed as
>   /usr/local/etc/openldap/slapd.conf) to
>   contain a BDB database definition of
>   the form:
>
> ```
>   database bdb
>   suffix "dc=<MY-DOMAIN>,dc=<COM>"
>   rootdn "cn=Manager,dc=<MY-DOMAIN>,dc=<COM>"
>   rootpw secret
>   directory /usr/local/var/openldap-data
> ```

But, my domain is either 127.0.1.1 or localhost,
What should I put instead of MY-DOMAIN and in COM ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put whatever you want. Suffix has nothing to do with what IPs/interfaces slapd listens on. Suffix is the top level of the data tree, it doesn't have to be DNS/network names.  Think of it as your database name.  So while you could use:

suffix "dc=localhost,dc=localdomain"

or

suffix "dc=example,dc=com"

you could also use:

suffix "dc=my,dc=ldap"

You can have more than two parts if you want

suffix "dc=my,dc=ldap,dc=server"

Comment: Since dc explicitly means domain-component, and is for those new-fangled DNS users who think that Internet domains matter :) you could always revert to an old-style setup based on components other than dc=.  This has the advantage of not causing confusion when systems try to locate servers with SRV records based on the dc path.

Answer (score 0):

I need some help please to configure ldap on localhost. Which info should I put on $LdapHost:$Port, NetworkId@$NetworkDomain, and Password. Thanks!

<beans:bean id="contextSource"
class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
<beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://$LdapHost:$Port" />
<beans:property name="userDn" value="NetworkId@$NetworkDomain" />
<beans:property name="password" value="Password" />
</beans:bean>

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vTop.png)