# OpenLDAP on CentOS 6.2 (@ localhost)

Tags: openldap, localhost, centos6.2, ldap

I'm trying to configure openldap on CentOS 6.2, I'm just testing openldap on my server at home, so I don't have any DNS server and stuff like that.

I already installed openldap using the following configuration:

```
Country Name (2 letter code) [XX]:US
State or Province Name (full name) []:Utah
Locality Name (eg, city) [Default City]:Utah
Organization Name (eg, company) [Default Company Ltd]:MyCompany
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Information Technology
Common Name (eg, your name or your server's hostname) []:localhost.localdomain
Email Address []:myemail@gmail.com
```

and the dc values as:

```
    dc=localhost,dc=localdomain
```

I already imported all the users and groups from my system to ldap without problems, I have an 'admin' account for openldap called 'Administrador'.

The problem is when I try to login using 'phpLDAPadmin', because every time I want to access with any of my users I received the following message:

> Unable to connect to LDAP server My LDAP Server Error: Invalid DN
>   syntax (34) for user  Failed to Authenticate to server Invalid
>   Username or Password.

Have you ever try to do something like that?
Is there any problem because my domain configuration?  (localhost.localdomain)

P.S: I already used the 'search' tool and I found this one, 
[how to configure open ldap to work on localhost](https://serverfault.com/questions/98730/how-to-configure-open-ldap-to-work-on-localhost)

Thank you guys in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Oh BTW, when I go to phpLDAPadmin on my browser, like I said above I can't using any of my accounts, but I can access to all my ldap details using 'Anonymous'.

that's weird, right?

Thank you in advance!.

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same problem. Did you figure out why only 'Anonymous' will let you browse the ldap content?